# Create Euler equation

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

I've tried to make some research, but without any luck.

How do I setup the [Euler equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) for this in Mathematica?:

$ \text{Min} \int_0^1\left(2x^2+ \left(4t-5 e^{r \, t} \right) x \, \dot{x} + 12e^{r \, t} \,\dot{x}^2 \right) dt,\; \; \text{for} \;  x(0)=1, \; \text{and} \; x(1)=e^{\frac{1}{6}}$

Thanks a lot guys, and happy friday.

Comment: Take a look at `VariationalMethods` in the help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]
eu = EulerEquations[2 x[t]^2 + (4 t - 5 E^(r t)) x'[t] x[t] +  12 E^(r t) x'[t]^2, {x[t]}, t]
s=DSolve[Join[eu, {x[0] == 0}, {x[1] == E^(1/6)}], x[t], t]

Plot[x[t] /. s /. r -> # & /@ Range[-5, 5], {t, 0, 1},  Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot[x[t] /. s, {t, 0, 1}, {r, -5, 5}, Evaluated -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style[t, 20, Bold], Style[r, Bold, 20]}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

**Edit**

The dynamics for several values of the parameter `r` and the velocity profiles:

```
p = Plot[D[x[t] /. s, t]/14 + # /. r -> # /. t -> u & /@ Range[-5, 5], {u, 0, E^(1/6)},              
         Evaluated -> True, Filling -> Table[{i -> i - 6}, {i, 1, 11}], Axes -> False];
rs = Flatten@{#, -#} &@Range@5;
ss = Animate[Show[
         Graphics[{Line[{{0, #}, {E^(1/6), #}}] & /@ rs, PointSize[Large], 
                   Table[Point[{(x[t] /. s[[1]] /. r -> u) /. t -> v, u}], {u, rs}]}, 
                  PlotRange -> {{0, E^(1/6)}, {-6, 6}}, 
                  FrameLabel -> {Style[t, 20, Bold], Style[r, Bold, 20]}, 
                  Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1], 
                 p], 
     {v, 0, 1, .01}]
```

[image]

Comment: you just missed the `s` so no mention!

Comment: Just to point out that one of your boundary conditions is different from the OP's. `x[0] == 1`.

Comment: @RunnyKine Thanks for pointing that out, I haven't noticed it. I think it doesn't make much difference to the system's dynamic behavior.

Comment: @Belisarius, yeah I figured it wouldn't make much of a difference, +1 by the way.

Comment: @RunnyKine Anyway, that's why the questions should always include Mma code. Retyping is an infinite source of errors ...

Comment: @belisarius I agree.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, I still wonder how to do it, if I have multiple constants. E.g. a and b are both positive constants in this example:

$$\text{min} \int_0^1 e^{a \dot{x}+bx} \; dt, \; \; \text{for } x(0)=0, \; \text{and} \; x(1)=0$$